# Animation while delete or reorder the cell in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to implement an animation when a user tries to delete and reorder a cell. Now it is coming instantly when I click on the edit button. Can you help me to make this code as an iphone contact app animation.

```
   -(IBAction)edit:(id)sender
   {
      tabView.editing = !tabView.editing;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW20) and you should be able to find the instance method you need.

The instance method *setEditing:animated:* will be able to do what you want. The second parameter will give the animation transition if you set it to YES.

For example:

```
[tabView setEditing:!tabView.editing animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks. But it is not working. I have used this.
-(IBAction)edit:(id)sender
{
    tabView.editing = !tabView.editing;
    [tabView setEditing:tabView.editing animated:YES];
} it goes off just after animation.

Comment: Opps so sorry.. Its working man. Thanks A lot.. i just forgot to remove previous code..